# How do I convert .asc data of CAN to .blf using python as per vector format

Tags: python, python-3.x, vector, ascii, can-bus

I have a .asc file, I want to convert it to .blf as per vector format.

I have tried,

```
from can.io import BLFWriter
import can
import pandas as pd
 
#input paths
path = '/home/ranjeet/Downloads/CAN/BLF_READER/input/'
asc_file = '20171209_1610_15017.asc'
blf_file = '20171209_1610_15017.blf'

df = pd.read_table(path + asc_file)
print(df)
```

I am able to read .asc, how do I write it to a .blf file as per vector format.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you reading your asc file with pandas if you're already working with the `python-can` module? 
You will find how to interact with asc and blf files in the doc [here](https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/can/io/asc.html) and [there](https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/can/io/blf.html?highlight=blf) respectively.

One thing you should pay attention to is to read/write blf files in binary mode. So in your example this should work (don't forget to stop the log otherwise the header will be missing):

```
import can

with open(asc_file, 'r') as f_in:
    log_in = can.io.ASCReader(f_in)

    with open(blf_file, 'wb') as f_out:
        log_out = can.io.BLFWriter(f_out)
        for msg in log_in:
            log_out.on_message_received(msg)
        log_out.stop()
```

Comment: Links are broken. Is there a new way to do this / new location for the docs? Maybe https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/stable/listeners.html#logger?

Comment: @jacobq thanks for noticing! It seems master branch is not published on readthedocs anymore. I changed it to stable :)